# OpenGL ES Tools for Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

Where can i find all the tools for designing complex Object in OpenGL ES?

like squares,cubes,sphers ect

Comment: You can use this Following Example of OPENGL ES http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/.

Comment: Hey MrComplicated how and where did you call upon that class you provided the code for above? Is there anyway you could post a zip file containing the example project? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just model your objects and export them to OBJ file, then you can simply load the OBJ file into your scene.

Here is the code I wrote to load my OBJ files which I exported them form Maya.
Kindly note that this is more like experimental code, so it is not clean, but I tested it and works perfectly.

Vector3D class holds the X,Y and Z variables, and Face class holds an ArrayList of UVWs, Vertices, and Vertex Normals.

And you have to draw your object by calling glDrawElements btw. 
Hope that this one will help =)

```
public class Model {

    // Constants
    private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    private static final int SHORT_SIZE_BYTES = 2;

    private FloatBuffer _vb;
    private FloatBuffer _nb;
    private ShortBuffer _ib;
    private FloatBuffer _tcb;

    private short[] indices;

    private float[] tempV;
    private float[] tempVt;
    private float[] tempVn;

    private ArrayList<Vector3D> vertices;
    private ArrayList<Vector3D> vertexTexture;
    private ArrayList<Vector3D> vertexNormal;
    private ArrayList<Face> faces;
    private int vertexCount;

    private ArrayList<GroupObject> groupObjects;

    //Android Stuff!
    private Context context;
    private int modelID;

    public Model(int modelID, Context activity)
    {
        this.vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3D>();
        this.vertexTexture = new ArrayList<Vector3D>();
        this.vertexNormal = new ArrayList<Vector3D>();
        this.faces = new ArrayList<Face>();

        this.groupObjects = new ArrayList<GroupObject>();

        this.modelID = modelID;
        this.context = activity;

        loadFile();
    }

    private int loadFile()
    {
        InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(modelID);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        try {
            loadOBJ(in);
            Log.d("LOADING FILE", "FILE LOADED SUCESSFULLY====================");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    private void loadOBJ(BufferedReader in) throws IOException
    {
        Log.d("LOADING FILE", "STARTING!====================");
        GroupObject defaultObject = new GroupObject();
        GroupObject currentObject = defaultObject;

        this.groupObjects.add(defaultObject);

        String Line;            // Stores ever line we read!
        String[] Blocks;        // Stores string fragments after the split!!
        String CommandBlock;    // Stores Command Blocks such as: v, vt, vn, g, etc...

        while((Line = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Blocks = Line.split(" ");
            CommandBlock = Blocks[0];

//          Log.d("COMMAND BLOCK" , "---------- " + CommandBlock + " ----------");

            if(CommandBlock.equals("g"))
            {
                if(Blocks[1] == "default")
                    currentObject = defaultObject;
                else
                {
                    GroupObject groupObject = new GroupObject();
                    groupObject.setObjectName(Blocks[1]);
                    currentObject = groupObject;
                    groupObjects.add(groupObject);
                }
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("v"))
            {
                Vector3D vertex = new Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3]));
                this.vertices.add(vertex);
//              Log.d("VERTEX DATA", " " + vertex.getX() + ", " + vertex.getY() + ", " + vertex.getZ());
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("vt"))
            {
                Vector3D vertexTex = new Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), 0.0f);
                this.vertexTexture.add(vertexTex);
//              Log.d("TEXTURE DATA", " " + vertexTex.getX() + ", " + vertexTex.getY() + ", " + vertexTex.getZ());
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("vn"))
            {
                Vector3D vertexNorm = new Vector3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3]));
                this.vertexNormal.add(vertexNorm);
//              Log.d("NORMAL DATA", " " + vertexNorm.getX() + ", " + vertexNorm.getY() + ", " + vertexNorm.getZ());
            }

            if(CommandBlock.equals("f"))
            {
                Face face = new Face();
                faces.add(face);

                String[] faceParams;

                for(int i = 1; i < Blocks.length ; i++)
                {               
                    faceParams = Blocks[i].split("/");

                    face.getVertices().add(this.vertices.get(Integer.parseInt(faceParams[0]) - 1));                 

                    if(faceParams[1] == ""){}
                    else
                    {
                        face.getUvws().add(this.vertexTexture.get(Integer.parseInt(faceParams[1]) - 1));
                        face.getNormals().add(this.vertexNormal.get(Integer.parseInt(faceParams[2]) - 1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

//      fillInBuffers();
        fillInBuffersWithNormals();

        Log.d("OBJ OBJECT DATA", "V = " + vertices.size() + " VN = " + vertexTexture.size() + " VT = " + vertexNormal.size());

    }

    private void fillInBuffers() {

        int facesSize = faces.size();

        vertexCount = facesSize * 3;

        tempV = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        tempVt = new float[facesSize * 2 * 3];
        indices = new short[facesSize * 3];

        for(int i = 0; i < facesSize; i++)
        {
            Face face = faces.get(i);
            tempV[i * 9]     = face.getVertices().get(0).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 1] = face.getVertices().get(0).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 2] = face.getVertices().get(0).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 3] = face.getVertices().get(1).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 4] = face.getVertices().get(1).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 5] = face.getVertices().get(1).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 6] = face.getVertices().get(2).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 7] = face.getVertices().get(2).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 8] = face.getVertices().get(2).getZ();
            tempVt[i * 6]     = face.getUvws().get(0).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 1] = face.getUvws().get(0).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 2] = face.getUvws().get(1).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 3] = face.getUvws().get(1).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 4] = face.getUvws().get(2).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 5] = face.getUvws().get(2).getY();
            indices[i * 3]     = (short) (i * 3);
            indices[i * 3 + 1] = (short) (i * 3 + 1);
            indices[i * 3 + 2] = (short) (i * 3 + 2);
        }

        _vb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempV.length
                * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _vb.put(tempV);
        _vb.position(0);

        _tcb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVt.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _tcb.put(tempVt);
        _tcb.position(0);

        _ib = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length
                * SHORT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        _ib.put(indices);
        _ib.position(0);
    }

    private void fillInBuffersWithNormals() {

        int facesSize = faces.size();

        vertexCount = facesSize * 3;

        tempV = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        tempVt = new float[facesSize * 2 * 3];
        tempVn = new float[facesSize * 3 * 3];
        indices = new short[facesSize * 3];

        for(int i = 0; i < facesSize; i++)
        {
            Face face = faces.get(i);
            tempV[i * 9]     = face.getVertices().get(0).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 1] = face.getVertices().get(0).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 2] = face.getVertices().get(0).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 3] = face.getVertices().get(1).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 4] = face.getVertices().get(1).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 5] = face.getVertices().get(1).getZ();
            tempV[i * 9 + 6] = face.getVertices().get(2).getX();
            tempV[i * 9 + 7] = face.getVertices().get(2).getY();
            tempV[i * 9 + 8] = face.getVertices().get(2).getZ();

            tempVn[i * 9]     = face.getNormals().get(0).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 1] = face.getNormals().get(0).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 2] = face.getNormals().get(0).getZ();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 3] = face.getNormals().get(1).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 4] = face.getNormals().get(1).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 5] = face.getNormals().get(1).getZ();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 6] = face.getNormals().get(2).getX();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 7] = face.getNormals().get(2).getY();
            tempVn[i * 9 + 8] = face.getNormals().get(2).getZ();

            tempVt[i * 6]     = face.getUvws().get(0).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 1] = face.getUvws().get(0).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 2] = face.getUvws().get(1).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 3] = face.getUvws().get(1).getY();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 4] = face.getUvws().get(2).getX();
            tempVt[i * 6 + 5] = face.getUvws().get(2).getY();

            indices[i * 3]     = (short) (i * 3);
            indices[i * 3 + 1] = (short) (i * 3 + 1);
            indices[i * 3 + 2] = (short) (i * 3 + 2);
        }

        _vb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempV.length
                * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _vb.put(tempV);
        _vb.position(0);

        _tcb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVt.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _tcb.put(tempVt);
        _tcb.position(0);

        _nb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(tempVn.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        _nb.put(tempVn);
        _nb.position(0);

        _ib = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length
                * SHORT_SIZE_BYTES).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        _ib.put(indices);
        _ib.position(0);
    }

    public FloatBuffer getVertices()
    {
        return _vb;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getTexCoords()
    {
        return _tcb;
    }

    public ShortBuffer getIndices()
    {
        return _ib;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getNormals() {
        return _nb;
    }
}
```

If this answers your question please vote for it ;)

Comment: +1 for reminding newcomers of the accept and up-vote features.

Comment: Thank you for your code , it really helped but the issue is , i want to draw complex objects , drawing a complex object like a car would be a pain using only vertices. i was wondering if their is a tool where we could make things easier  .  the code that u offered only loads an object already made.  please relply

Comment: If you want to make (or model) complex objects, you have to learn how to model a 3D object. You have Blender which is free, and there are tons of tutorials over the internet on how to use it and model complex 3D objects. Other software like Maya and 3DS Max will do the job as well but you need to buy a license for them. And of course once you finish modeling, you need to export the models into OBJ format in order for the code which I posted to work ;)

Comment: i started learning blender, its pretty cool . i know this may seem to be a dumb question . blender can supports animation and game engine. once my my animation project is done ,i export my file to a .OBJ file and after i import it in android will the animation show on the emulator , and does ur code support it ?

Comment: and what is the COLLADA THINGY ?

Comment: As for COLLADA, read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA
And your question about animation, OBJ file format doesn't store any information about animation, bones or anything... it just stores the **mesh information** and its materials, nothing more. So you gonna animate the whole object, you cannot animate parts. The code which I posted it supports loading OBJs which I exported from Maya, and animated them successfully on my HTC desire HD.

Comment: @mrcomplicated very helpful! Thanks! UPVOTE! Please could you add the code for the `Vector3D` `Face` and  `GroupObject` ? Thanks!!! LISA

Answer (score 1):

You could use blender and libgdx library.
I tried libgdx which is great but never for 3d.
A tutorial to start with blender for libgdx: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/BlenderModels